# How do I stop cropping in iMovie?

Tags: mac, imovie

I'm not certain if 'crop' is the right term.  I'm new to iMovie so I may have some of the terminology wrong.

When I import a movie, I allow it to resize to the recommended settings instead of full size.

Then I drag it from the lower event pane into the project pane. In the 'preview' pane where the movie can be played, the top and bottom of the movie are cut off a little.

It's like its converting it to widescreen by cutting off the top and bottom.

After I publish the movie in mobile format (it won't allow any larger) it still has the top and bottom removed.

How can I stop this?  I even tried importing full (original) size and it still didn't help.

Comment: Do you know the pixel dimensions and/or the codec? Where did the video come from? If a camera, which make and model?

Comment: It came from a Canon A480. Format Apple OpenDML JPEG, 320 x 240, Millions, 8-but unsigned integer, mono, 11.024 khz, fps 30, data rate 3,588.74 kbit/s, current size 478 x 359 pixels.  This is from quicktime.  when I export it to mobile, it turns into 480 x 272.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is 4.5 years late, but have not seen any solutions the same as what I figured out.

Using iMovie 10.0.5, I fixed this with (obviously not needed if already visible)

Windows->Show Adjustments Bar

Above the preview window, there is the "Cropping" icon. For the "style" options, select "Fit" not "Crop to Fit".